# Find a fraction with the smallest denominator

Tags: code-golf

## Input

Two non-negative floating point numbers \$x < y\$. You can assume they are close enough to each other that there is no integer between \$x\$ and \$y\$.

## Output

A fraction with the smallest possible denomination that lies strictly between \$x\$ and \$y\$.

## Examples

Input: 1 and 2

Output: 3/2

Input: 0 and 0.33

Output: 1/4

Input: 0.4035 and 0.4036

Output: 23/57

Comment: How do we deal with float imprecision? Say we're given the float representing 1/3 which actually equals `0.3333333333333333148...`, is the fraction 1/3 greater than that?

Comment: @xnor The input is a float so if it just has 3s in its decimal expansion, it is less than 1/3. Is this going to cause a difficulty?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate, but I can't find the original.

Comment: @WheatWizard Are you thinking of [In between fractions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/247654/92901)? The only difference in that challenge is that \$x\$ and \$y\$ are fractions instead of floats.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 42 bytes

```javascript
x=>g=(y,d)=>(p=-~(x*d))<y*d?[p,d]:g(y,-~d)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1i7dVqNSJ0XT1k6jwFa3TqNCK0VT06ZSK8U@ukAnJdYqHSirW5ei@T85P684PydVLyc/XSNNw1BTw0hTkwtV0EBTw0DP2BhTXM/EwNhUE0KbaWr@BwA)

If \$ \left \lfloor xd \right \rfloor +1  < yd \$, then \$ \left \lfloor xd \right \rfloor +1   \$ is an answer

Comment: Which is fortunate since `⌈xd⌉<yd` is the wrong test.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 47 bytes

Expects `(x)(y)`, returns `[numerator, denominator]`.

```javascript
(x,p=q=1)=>g=y=>p<y*q++&&p++>x*--q?[--p,q]:g(y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcixDoIwEADQ3Q8hd5RrilUHw9UPMQ4EodEQegVj6NfXwYkwveS922@7dPNLPjSFZ58HzrBWwpFrZOc5sZMmlVGpohCl3FoSxdudSKr4uHpImLswLWHs9Rg8DFAjHBEP2zQIRlu7f30y9ox/L4j5Bw)

#### Commented

```javascript
( x,          // x = first number
  p =         // p = numerator
  q = 1       // q = denominator
) =>          //
g = y =>      // y = second number
p < y * q++   // we test whether p/q < y
              // and increment q afterwards in case it's not
&&            // if truthy,
p++ > x * --q // we restore q, test whether p/q > x
              // and increment p afterwards in case it's not
?             // if truthy again:
  [--p, q]    //   we restore p and return [p, q]
:             // else:
  g(y)        //   we try again with either p or q incremented
```

Comment: But how does it work?

Comment: @Simd I've added a commented version. This is a really simple algorithm, but written in a slightly convoluted way.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 bytes

```
×ḞĊƭ€r/ḊṖ
1ç1#Ḣṭç¥
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///w9Ic75h3pOrb2UdOaIv2HO7oe7pzGZXh4uaHywx2LHu5ce3j5oaX/dQ63P9y5D6gi61HDHAVdO4VHDXO5DrcDBSL//4/mijbUMYrV4Yo20DHQMzYGs/RMDIxNdcCUWSxXLAA)

A pair of links which is called as a monad with a pair of floats and returns a pair of `[numerator, denominator]`.

### Explanation

````
×ḞĊƭ€r/ḊṖ | Helper link: takes a denominator as the left argument and a pair of floats as the right and returns a valid numerator, if any
×         | Multiply (denominator with floats)
 ḞĊƭ€     | Floor first, ceiling second
     r/   | Reduce using range
       ḊṖ | Remove first and last

1ç1#Ḣṭç¥ | Main link
1ç1#     | Starting with one, find first denominator where there’s a valid numerator (will be wrapped in a list)
    Ḣ    | Head (to unwrap the list)
     ṭç¥ | Tag this onto the result of  running the helper link again to find the numerator
```
````

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 33 bytes

```
ＮθＮη≔⌕Ｅ⁺²∕¹⁻ηθ⁻⌈×ηι⌊×θι²ζＩ⟦⊖⌈×ηζζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY0xC4MwEIV3f4XjBaxYp4JTUYQOFodupUOqhx7EU5Po4J9PU2mh0OGG73u8d00vdTNK5dyFp8Vel@GJGmaRBb/cez4bQx1DSdxCJSeo1WIgjcKCVmoRjlFYEXvVR@EshPhijqSIO7jRgHtI76xU46g/bt6dl6m/zX@qNbGFXBoL9wIbjQOyxfZ/attr20OIzLkkToMkPrnDql4) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＮθＮη
```

Input `x` and `y`.

```
≔⌕Ｅ⁺²∕¹⁻ηθ⁻⌈×ηι⌊×θι²ζ
```

Find `d` such that `⌈yd⌉-⌊xd⌋=2`. `d` is never more than `⌊1+1/(y-x)⌋`, but I have to add `2` due to 0-indexing.

```
Ｉ⟦⊖⌈×ηζζ
```

Output `⌈yd⌉-1` and `d`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 95 bytes

```python
(a,b),(c,d)=[input().as_integer_ratio()for m in 0,0]
while(m*d/c+1)*a>=m*b:m+=1
print m,m*d/c+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LctBDsIgEADAO6/gyNINbu3NBD9iTENbtJu4QBBjfD168DyZ8ml7TsfeTcAF0Ky4gb9wKq9mwIXnzKnFe6xzDY2zgVuuWjQnTUhX9d75EY3Y7bAOI9hw9mKXkwx@VKX@phb8Y@/kSJGbJvUF)

Not a math guy, basically uses the formula of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2494861/596406).

The input should be in decimal format: `1.0` instead of just `1`.

*-2* bytes: replace `//` with `/`

*-4* bytes: inlining `m`

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 47 bytes

```r
\(x,y){while((p=(x*F)%/%1+1)>=y*F)F=F+1
c(p,F)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY39WM0KnQqNavLMzJzUjU0Cmw1KrTcNFX1VQ21DTXtbCuBHDdbN21DrmSNAh03zVqoNsU0DUMdI02uNA0DHQM9Y2MwS8_EwNhUB0yZaUIULlgAoQE)

Port of [@l4m2's JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269186/55372).